# Elasticsearch result scoring

Tags: elasticsearch

**Question1:** I want to sort the results based on the number of terms matched. How to do it?

```
POST _search
{
   "query": {

       "match": {
           "myfields":{
               "query": "abate chicanery disseminate gainsay latent aberrant coagulate dissolution",
               "operator": "or"
           }

       } 
    }
}
```

If Doc1 contains 3 words while doc2 contains 2, I want Doc1 to be scored most.

**Question2:**

How to see which words at matched in the result? and how many times?

Comment: First request is possible. Second one is possible with `highlighting`.

Comment: @AndreiStefan How to ignore term frequency?